# how people will establish salat ( أَقِمِ ٱلصَّلَوٰةَ)?

Tags: quran, hadith, salat, fiqh, sharia

**Firstly Allah will judge/account for salat on the Day of Judgment...**

*[The triliteral root ṣād lām wāw (ص ل و) occurs 99 times in the Quran, in four derived forms:](https://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=Slw)*

**Verses**

> And establish prayer and give zakah and bow with those who bow [in worship and obedience]. **- [Surah Al-Baqara Verse 43](https://qurano.com/en/2-al-baqara/verse-43/)**

> [O Muhammad], what has been revealed to you of the Book and establish prayer. Indeed, prayer prohibits immorality and wrongdoing, and the remembrance of Allah is greater. And Allah knows that which you do. **- [Surah Al-Ankabut Verse 45](https://qurano.com/en/29-al-ankabut/verse-45/)**

> O my son, establish prayer, enjoin what is right, forbid what is wrong, and be patient over what befalls you. Indeed, [all] that is of the matters [requiring] determination.[Surah Luqman Verse 17](https://qurano.com/en/31-luqman/verse-17/)

**Personal Thinking**

***what is meaning  of establish prayer***

Form the verse

> ***[O Muhammad], what has been revealed to you of the Book and establish prayer.***

Personally I think, People can be a ruler/king/president or leader in a society or an small area ,

As a person, according to his ability/position /power ,

what are  vital steps, he should take ?

what are the  role for establishing salat ? or maybe more or less...

I think above those scenario/situation  related to establishing salat or ***maybe I am wrong***

***My Main Question***

question is `how people will establish salat ( أَقِمِ ٱلصَّلَوٰةَ)?`

***I am looking for the answer according to the Quran/Hadith/Fiqh/Sharia or Islamic scholar ? or in Islamic view***

Comment: These are many sub questions in one post. Please clarify what you mean with your first sub question: "*How or when this responsibility is come?*" because to me is unclear what your expectation is. However I'd rather recommend you to focus on your 2nd sub question "How to establish salat?" and maybe check whether it was asked before.

Comment: @Medi1Saif♦   _"How or when this responsibility is come?" _ That means in your family/society/country, your position/ability/power as a father/friend/brother/ruler/king/leader what step you need to take or what is your rule as like as your position

Comment: Then this looks like a question asking about the idea / philosophy on the content. However this is only concluded from the qur'an and sunnah as neither of both is concrete enough in all related topics.

Comment: @Medi1Saif♦ I am not looking for any idea.... Allah order that establish `salat`...  so there are responsibly... _Perform salat myself will fulfill responsibility as a Muslim person, without establish salat?_  _`قِمِ-ٱلصَّلَوٰةَ`_  is imperative sentence.. is it not a command ?

Comment: Are you asking about history / how and when Salat was established or are you asking for personal responsability of a muslim? - It is difficult to understand your topic.

Comment: I'm not sure whether a bounty would help to answer a question which seem unclear and broad.

Comment: @Sassir how people will establish salat ( أَقِمِ ٱلصَّلَوٰةَ)?  I update my question ..  if anything did not understand pleas ask

Comment: Are you trying to ask how we determine the method of establishing salah, when it is not described how to do so in the Quran?

Comment: @moinudin Allah said about in the holy Quran.. but we need to understand.. we need to tafseer it ?  I write about it `according to the Quran/Hadith/Fiqh/Sharia or Islamic scholar ? or in Islamic view`

Comment: The Quran commands us to establish salah. We come to learn how to establish salah through the actions (Sunnah) of the Prophet صلى الله عليه وسلم. His actions were recorded by the Companions رضى الله تعالى عنهم, and these are what we follow today. Does that answer your question?